# Can I install a driver only through modifying registry?

Tags: windows, installation, registry, kernel, driver

To my knowledge, there are at least four approches to install a kernel driver:

1. Through SetupXXX;
2. Through Service Manager;
3. Through INF file;
4. Through Registry;

Provided that I have a minifilter driver, I just wonder if the following installation steps work?

Step 1. Copy the MyDriver.sys to

> %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\

Step 2. Add a subkey named `mydriver` under

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services

Step 3. Add some values like `Start`, `Type`, `Tag`, `Group`, `Altitude`, `ImagePath`, etc. under the subkey `mydriver`;

Step 4. Set the value Start to 0, i.e. tell OS to load MyDriver.sys at boot time;

Step 5. Reboot.

My questions is: Are there disadvantages of this method?

Comment: AFAIK this approach is unsupported, so it wouldn't be suitable for production software.  For example, it might work on your machine but not on a customer machine.  If it will only be installed in-house by IT professionals you might get away with it.

Comment: I don't really see the point of modifying the registry directly; that's essentially what the Service Control Manager API does, but it has the added benefit of updating the in-memory structures so the system sees the driver immediately rather than requiring a reboot.  And as Harry says, it's better to use supported methods than unsupported methods.

Comment: For testing this clearly has advantages, yes I know the whole should be using a virtual machine line. But will this work, to get the driver doing quick and easy then later you can make a proper installation program, or even register it for windows logo and to be included with windows updates automatically

Comment: Also this would work for a device which is always installed, but it would associate a device. I have question, are all drivers just services?